# How to safely act as root during automated deploy

Tags: git, apache, deployment, sudo

I am currently developing a deployment script using the PHP-based Rocketeer. During a deploy run, and before checking out new code from Git I would like to stop the Apache service. Is there a very safe way to do this from the deploy script? At the moment all I can find are three options which I'm not wild about:

- Give the deploy ssh user passwordless sudo access to stop/start Apache
- Switch the deploy ssh user to root
- Use `expect` with `su` to switch to root as needed

For option one, I don't want the user that Apache runs as to have passwordless sudo access because this seems like it makes my web application more vulnerable. For option two, I don't want to allow root access via ssh at all. For option three, this would require setting the root password, and then storing it in a flat file as part of the deploy script, which is not ideal.

Comment: Option one gives the deploy user passwordless access to restart Apache, not the Apache user passwordless access to sudo. That's the best option.

Comment: Perhaps my problem then, is that I'm using the Apache user as the deploy user. Seemed to make sense since default file ownership would be correct during the deploy, etc. but I take your point.

Comment: Consider writing a script to run with sudo, and only give that user permission to run sudo with that script.